# meaning of wonder

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, sentence

I have a problem with the word "wonder" in this sentence:

One may **wonder** of course whether ‘numbers’ are anything we encounter in an ordinary life.

Here, "wonder" means "feeling amazement, surprise" or "feeling doubt"?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to ELU. See also [ell.se]. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

It means neither of those options.  Rather, it means, "to think or speculate curiously."

https://www.dictionary.com/browse/wonder?s=t (see definition 1)

Answer (score -1):

Here, *wonder* basically means *want to know*, as *wonder*, *want* and *wish* (Ger "Wunsch") are cognate with a root PIE *wenH- reconstructed as "desire, wish, love". A sense of *awe*, *amazement* is apparent in *wonder*, yes.